# Compiler version issue for Node.js C++ addon development

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, name-mangling, node.js-addon

I know that the C++ program is compiler dependent due to the name mangling. So I have the following questions regarding C++ addon for Node.js.

1. How do we know which C++ compiler is used for the pre-build Node.js distribution on my machine (Mac, Windows or Linux)?
2. If I know the exact compiler version of the installed Node.js, then I am supposed to use the same compiler to develop C++ addon, right?

Thank you.

Comment: You would only have name mangling issues if you were distributing a binary package -- you should not try to distribute a binary package.

Answer (score 0):

Your node add-on's should be distributed as source code in the NPM module.  The `npm install` will compile it locally on the machine that will use it, and the machine installing it will decide what version of the compiler will be used.

You should not and cannot distribute NPM modules with binary objects the way you state in your question for the exact reason you describe in your question.

Look to use the npm module `nan` to do your C++ add-on.

Comment: How do you make sure the compiler of target machine matches the compiler of the node?

Comment: The node installation on the target machine should match the target machine itself -- most people compile node from sources or uses the binary that has been precompiled for their specific environment.

Comment: @LinZ -- In short, as a node-extension developer it is **not your job** to ensure that the compilers matches -- it is the end-users responsibility to make sure they have installations that is consistent with their environment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! If I am asked by a user that which building environment he needs to prepare, I just point him to the the Node.js website, right?

Comment: You should follow the example on the `nan` link I provided